# Replace null values to empty values in a JSON OBJECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I've got a JSON object provided by an ajax request.

Some of the values inside the json appears as `null`, but I want an `empty String` instead

My sample of code :

```
$.post("/profil_process/wall/preview-post.php",param, function (data){
    // this does not work
    JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value) { return value === "" ? "" : value });
    $('#previewWall').html(getPostWall(data.type,data.titre,data.url,data.description,data.media,data.photo_auteur,data.nom_auteur,data.url_auteur,data.date_publication)).fadeIn();
    $(".bouton-vertM").show();
    $("#wLoader").hide();
},'json');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code says that if the value is an empty string, then the empty string should be returned; if it's anything else, then the value should be returned as-is. Thus, it's exactly equivalent to just `return value;`

Comment: Shouldn't you compare it to `null`?

Comment: You realize that `data` doesn't really change even if you stringify the object like that ?

Comment: @Kuma: Where did you get that code from? It doesn't appear in the revision history.

Comment: @BoltClock, I believe it was edited first by him (to narrow down the code) before I applied my edit. See one answer here that contains the same code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your function should be like this:

```
function (key, value) {
    return (value === null) ? "" : value;
}
```

If the `value` is null, then it returns an empty string.

Comment: `value == null` will be true when value is either `null` or `undefined`, so there's no need for any further comparison.

Comment: my data.description is still null after applying : JSON.stringify(data, function (key, value) {return (value == null) ? "" : value});

Comment: @Anthony - As I commented on the answer, this doesn't change *anything*, strings are immutable, and the object surely isn't updated just because you decided to stringify it.

Comment: Correct, as @adeneo said, that function only works while rendering the json as string, but it doesn't change the value of any fields inside the original JSON. To do that you should process the original JSON variable and change values...

Comment: This could be refactored to `return value || ""`;

Comment: Should not use `return value || ""` . 0 or false will be empty string, either.

Comment: @KevinFarrugia not that, for reason that @kook mentioned, but you could do null-coalescing: `return value ?? ''` without those weird side effects.

Answer (score 21):

If you can replace null-s with empty strings on serialized string, do something like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\:null/gi, "\:\"\""));
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to use the built in replacer argument rather than a string replace ?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this would be bad idea, in cases where we use serialized JSON string anyway and when it wouldn't affect performance

Comment: But JSON.stringify has a built in replacer as the second argument, which is what the OP is using. Don't you think it would be a better idea to use the built in replacer argument than to create your own for no apparent reason ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think about this as clean on-line-solution, but I definitely agree with you that built-in solutions should always have priority over custom solutions.

Comment: This is a horrible idea.

Comment: Worked perfect for my use, thank you

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you should be doing it, replacing the objects values with empty strings, not stringifying it

```
$.post("/profil_process/wall/preview-post.php",param, function (data){

    (function removeNull(o) {
        for(var key in o) {
            if( null === o[key] ) o[key] = '';
            if ( typeof o[key] === 'object' ) removeNull(o[key]);
        }
     })(data);

     $('#previewWall').html(
          getPostWall(
              data.type,
              data.titre,data.url,
              data.description,
              data.media,
              data.photo_auteur,
              data.nom_auteur,
              data.url_auteur,
              data.date_publication
          )  // ^^^ why not just pass the entire object ?
    ).fadeIn();

    $(".bouton-vertM").show();
    $("#wLoader").hide();

},'json');
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for a solution.

Used this in my angular 2 app to remove all null values returned by my db query.

Create an angular 2 function in the component

```
    replacer(i, val) {
     if ( val === null ) 
     { 
        return ""; // change null to empty string
     } else {
        return val; // return unchanged
     }
    }
```

Or Javascript function

```
    function replacer(i, val) {
     if ( val === null ) 
     { 
        return ""; // change null to empty string
     } else {
        return val; // return unchanged
     }
    }
```

Then use the function in JSON.stringify method

```
    JSON.stringify(result, this.replacer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the check the return type of the Ajax because it determines how to remove `null`.

If it is string, you can use this:

```
data = data.replace(/null/g, '""');  //Stays as string
```

Or:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);    // Turns to a JSON object
```

If it is `json` object, then you can use this:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/null/g, '""');  //Turns to string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code that will convert all `null` values into an empty `string`

```js
let myObject = {
  "id":1,
  "name": "Ali",
  "address":null,
  "phone":null,
  "age":22
}
Object.keys(myObject).map(function (key, index) {
                if (myObject[key] == null) {
                    myObject[key] = "";
                }
            });
console.log(myObject); 

// output
/* {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ali",
  "address": "",
  "phone": "",
  "age": 22
}  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore mapObject gave me the most compact solution.  Here's a complete example:

```
$ npm install underscore

import _, { map, each } from 'underscore';
var x = {a:null, b:1, c:'c', d:null}
var y = _.mapObject(x, function(val, key) {
            return val || '';
        });
console.log('No nulls:', y)

No nulls: {a:"", b:1, c:"c", d:""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party buy hey/ho.

The below function is the exact opposite of what you need, so just reverse engineer :D

In order to swap empty string's or strings with spaces in JSON we will need to iterate through the keys and check if a value contains an empty string.

You can complete this, easily with the .trim method. We basically check, if the length of the string trimmed, (without spaces) is equal to 0. If so we will add the same key to our new object but add a null value instead. You could also remove the length in the trim call and check if obj[keys].trim == ''.

```
      function myFunction(obj){
      const newObj = {}

      for(keys in obj){
      if(obj[keys].trim().length == 0){
      newObj[keys] = null; 
      }
      else{
      newObj[keys] = obj[keys];
      }
   }

   return newObj;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the correct way to do it in JS*

```js
let data = {
    "msg": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "firstName": "Manish",
            "lastName": "Pal",
            "age": 23
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Deepak",
            "lastName": "Gupta",
            "age": null
        }
    ],
    "salary": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "SD",
            "amount": 1000000
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "C",
            "ok": null
        }
    ]
};

let mainResponse = {};

const replaceNull = (value) => {
    return (value == null) ? "" : value
}
//Parse Json and check for null
const removeNullFromJson = (object1, jsonObj) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            jsonObj[key] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                jsonObj[key].push(removeNullFromJson(value[i], {}))
            }
        }
        else if (typeof value == "object" && value != null) {
            jsonObj[key] = removeNullFromJson(value, {})
        }
        else {
            jsonObj[key] = replaceNull(value);
        }
    }
    return jsonObj
}

console.log(removeNullFromJson(data, mainResponse))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help

```
var List = [];


$.post("/profil_process/wall/preview-post.php",param, function (data){

jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
                List.push({
                    ReportId : value.ReportId,
                    ReportType: CheckNullReturnBlank(value.ReportType),
                    ReportName: CheckNullReturnBlank(value.ReportName),
                    Description : CheckNullReturnBlank(value.Description)
                })
            });   },'json');



function CheckNullReturnBlank(item) {
    return item = (item == null) ? '' : item;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace null values to empty by below code in java-script

```
var remove_empty = function ( target ) {
  Object.keys( target ).map( function ( key ) {
    if ( target[ key ] instanceof Object ) {
      if ( ! Object.keys( target[ key ] ).length && typeof target[ key ].getMonth !== 'function') {
        target[ key ] = "";
      }
      else {
        remove_empty( target[ key ] );
      }
    }
    else if ( target[ key ] === null ) {
       target[ key ] = "";
    }
  } );
  return target;
};
```

you can read more about [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score -2):

```
function returnblank(item){
  if(item == null){
    return "";
  }else{
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would not hurt.

Comment: Please try and add an explanation to your answer.