# How do you stringify and parse the response from UrlFetchApp with replacer function?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm using the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) class and trying to replace all the `null` values in the response with an empty string. I found that you can use the [replacer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203463/replace-null-values-to-empty-values-in-a-json-object) as the 2nd parameter in the `JSON.stringify()` function like so: `JSON.stringify(value, replacer function)`. The problem is I can only get the `stringify()` function to work if I create my variable holding the object like this:

```
var myVar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com')), replacer))
```

where `replacer` is this:

```
function replacer(key, value) { return (value == null) ? 0 : value }
```

Needing to `parse()`, `stringify()`, and then `parse()` again just to get the proper JSON object in `myVar` seems redundant. Is there another way to parse and stringify the response?

### Edit 1/8/21

Based on @Tanaike's response, found out you can use `JSON.parse()` with a replacer function, so my final expressions looks like this (where `replacer` equals the function above):

```
var myVar = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com'), replacer)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to parse the result of UrlFetchApp, it's already an object

Comment: I tried stringifying the result of UrlFetchApp, and it would result in an empty object. Even adding the replacer function, the result was still {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the value of `null` in the object retrieved from the URL to an empty string using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, in order to retrieve the response value from UrlFetchApp, how about using the method of `getContentText()`? In this case, the response value can be retrieved as the string. And, I think that `JSON.parse` can be also used for replacing the value. By this, I think that your script can be modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myVar = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com').getContentText(), (_, value) => value == null ? "" : value);
  console.log(myVar)
}
```

- In this modification, the value of `null` is replaced with `""` which is an empty string using `JSON.parse`.
- Above modification, the result value can be used as the JSON object. But, if you want to use `JSON.stringify`, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    var myVar = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com').getContentText()), (_, value) => value == null ? "" : value);
  ```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8 runtime.
- `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` returns `HTTPResponse`. But when I test the following script, the value could be retrieved without the error. When I tested before, an error occurred. So I thought that the specification might be changed at Google side. But this is just my guess.

  ```
    var myVar = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com'), (_, value) => value == null ? "" : value);
  ```

#### References:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [getContentText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText())
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: It looks like the replacer function works with JSON.parse, so you don't even need the stringify function. getContentText() doesn't change the result, so my final URL looks like this: JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://someurl.com'), (_, value) => value == null ? "" : value)